# Can we Smoothly Choose a Line Fixed by a Smoothly Rotating Rigid Body?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, physics, smooth-manifolds

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf R}$ The question below is motivated by the fact that each non-identity member of $SO(3)$ fixes exactly one line pointwise in $\R^3$.

Let $f:\R\to SO(3)$ be a *smooth* map (which models a smoothly rotating pivoted rigid body in $\R^3$).

> **Question.** Does there necessarily exist a smooth map $g:\R\to \mathbf RP^2$ such that $f(t)$ fixes $g(t)$ pointwise for each $t$.

The question above has negative answer if we do not require $f$ to be smooth but only continuous. For then we can take $f$ to be as follows: for $t\in [0, 1]$ we define $f(t)$ as rotation about the $z$-axis by $2\pi t$, and for $t\in [1, 2]$ we deifne $f(t)$ as rotation about the $x$-axis by $2\pi (t-1)$. For all other $t$ we define $f(t)=I$. Now if there exists a continuous $g:\R\to \R P^2$ such that $f(t)$ fixes $g(t)$, then for $t\in (0, 1)$ we must have $g(t)$ is the $z$-axis, and for $t\in (1, 2)$, $g(t)$ equals the $x$-axis. Thus $g(1)$ cannot take any value without destroying continuity.

Of course, this counterexample does not work for smooth case.

Comment: In case it matters, the first sentence is not quite OK as stated: the half-turn about an axis fixes the axis (the $1$-eigenspace) and the plane orthogonal to that axis (the $-1$-eigenspace). (Thus, there is a unique line of fixed points, but not a unique fixed -- i.e., _invariant_ --line.) That aside, I believe it's easy to check that the map from $SO(3) \setminus\{I\}$ to the projective plane sending a rotation to its $1$-eigenspace is smooth, so the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you for your comment. What I had in mind was pointwise fixed line, rather than just a line fixed as a set. I admit that this could cause confusion. That aside, I am unable to follow how you are able to answer the question in the affirmative by the last line in your comment.

Comment: Your counterexample also works for the smooth case if instead of a piecewise linear rotation you use a combination of [bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function). I think you will require Andrew's additional condition that the range of $f$ does not include the identity.

Comment: It's not true. You can even make the counterexample you gave smooth by using bump functions. On the other hand, if your path $ f $ is regular as it passes through the identity, then  I think it projects to $ \mathbb{R} P ^2 $.

Comment: @user81327 Thank you for your comment. Can you explain what is meant by a regular path? Thanks.

Comment: Think of $ SO(3) $ as the ball of radius $ \pi $ with antipodal points of the boundary identified. There is clearly a map from $ SO(3) \ \{I \}  $ to $ \mathbb{R}P^2 $ by normalizing. What can you do if your path goes through the identity? It looks like if the path has a well defined tangent vector as it passes through the identity, then sending the path at identity to it's normalized tangent vector seems to be a continuous extension.

Comment: @Rahul and user81327 Thank you both. Your comment about bump functions solved my issue. I am thinking about user81327's last comment which is quite interesting.

Comment: @user81327 I am thinking on your comment. Meanwhile, can you please tell me how you are getting a map $SO(3)\setminus \{I\}$ to $\R P^2$? The way I got this map was by first thinking of $SO(3)$ as $\R P^3$ and then deformation retracting the punctured $\R P^3$ to $\R P^2$. This is rather indirect so I am interested in your approach. Thanks.