# Definition and Existence of Angular Velocity

Tags: differential-geometry, physics

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf R}$ Let $f:\R\to SO(3)$ be a smooth map whose derivative never vanishes. So $f(t)$ can be thought of as the snapshot at time $t$ of a rigid pivoted at the origin and rotating smoothly about the pivot.

In my high school physics books, the **angular velocity** at time $t$ of a rigid body pivoted at a point was defined as a vector $\vec\omega(t)\in \R^3$ such that if $\vec p(t)$ is the position vector of a particle $P$ on the rigid body at time $t$, then the velocity of $P$ at $t$ is $\vec\omega(t)\times \vec p(t)$.

Under this definition, I want to know if we can prove that the angular velocity of a smoothly rotating rigid body always exists.

If $f:\mathbf R\to SO(3)$ is a smoothly rotating rigid body with $f(0)=Id$, and $v\in \R^3$ is a point, then define $P_v(t)=f(t)v$. (Here $f(t)$ is a linear map which is begin fed $v$).

Basically $P_v(t)$ is the position of the paritcle of the rigid body at time $t$ which was at $v$ at time $0$. So the velocity of this particle at time $t$ is $\dot P_v(t)$.

> Can somebody see as to why at any given time $t$ we have a vector $\omega(t)\in \R^3$ such that $\omega(t)\times P_v(t)=\dot P_v(t)$ for all $v\in \R^3$?

Further, does $\omega(t)$ vary smoothly with $t$?

Thank you.

Comment: Sketch of proof: (i) $\dot P_v(t) = f'(t)v$. (ii) $f(t)^Tf(t)=I\implies f'(t)=-f'(t)^T$. (iii) $f'(t)=\begin{bmatrix}0&c&-b\\-c&0&a\\b&-a&0\end{bmatrix}$. (iv) $f'(t)v=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}\times v$.

Comment: @Travis Since one single $\omega$ should work for all $v$, the $\omega$ should be unique. This is because all the points lying on the one dimensional subspace spanned by $\omega$ have $0$ velocity, and no other point has $0$ velocity.

Comment: @Rahul The conclusion in (ii) only holds when $f(t) = Id$. In general we have that $f(t)^{\top} f'(t)$ is skew-symmetric.

Comment: @caffeinemachine Yes, you're right, of course, I didn't notice the stipulation for general $v$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Euler's rotation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_rotation_theorem), any value of $f$ can be represented by a single rotation about a fixed axis,

$$
f=e^A,
$$

where $A$ is an antisymmetric matrix. In your application, $A$ is a continuous function of time with $A(0)=0$. Although the matrix $A$ described by Euler's theorem may not be unique, it is unique in this application because $A$ is continuous and connected to the zero matrix. The position of a point on the body is

$$
P_v = fv,
$$

and differentiation gives

$$
\frac{dP_v}{dt} = e^A\frac{dA}{dt}v.
$$

To prove what you want to prove, it's sufficient to prove it at $t=0$, where this simplifies to
$$
\left.\frac{dP_v}{dt}\right|_0 = \left.\frac{dA}{dt}\right|_0v.
$$
Let's drop the $|_0$ symbols for convenience. The matrix $dA/dt$ is antisymmetric, and its components can be identified with the components of the angular velocity vector:
$$
  A =\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & \omega_z & -\omega_y \\
  -\omega_z & 0 & \omega_x \\
  \omega_y & -\omega_x & 0
  \end{pmatrix}.
$$
This value of the vector $\omega$ was calculated in a way that didn't depend on the choice of $v$, so that completes the proof.

Stepping back and looking at the big picture here, there are really two things that make all this work. (1) In 3 dimensions, we have an isomorphism between antisymmetric matrices and vectors. This isomorphism only works in 3 dimensions. (2) Rotations are not commutative, but infinitesimal rotations are, so that there is no $\Delta \theta$ vector, but there is a $d\theta$ vector.

> Further, does $\omega(t)$ vary smoothly with $t$?

You say that $f$ is a smooth map, so yes, because all we did in order to find $\omega$ was differentiate and pick components out of a matrix. Actually all you really need is that $f$ be twice differentiable. Otherwise, for example, I can simply make up an example of rotation in the x-y plane by an angle $\theta(t)$, where $\theta''(t)$ doesn't exist at a certain time.

Comment: Thank you for the most enlightening answer. To see why there is a smooth map $A$ taking $\mathbf R$ to the space of linear isometries of $\mathbf R^3$ such that $f=e^A$, I have the following rather non-elementary argument. We equip $SO(3)$ by a bi-invariant metric (this can be done since $SO(3)$ is compact). Then we know that that the exponential map of $SO(3)$ when $SO(3)$ is thought of as a Lie group is same as the exponential map at the identity of $SO(3)$ when $SO(3)$ is thought as a Riemannian manifold. Now the Cartan-Hadamard theorem implies that $\exp:T_I(SO(3))\to SO(3)$ is a smooth...

Comment: ... covering map. Thus $f:\mathbf R\to SO(3)$ admits a smooth lifting to yield the desired smooth map $A$, and we are done. If you have a more elementary argument then can you please post it? Thanks.

Comment: My reasoning is inaccurate. For me to apply the Cartan-Hadamard theorem I need to show that the sectional curvature of $SO(3)$ is always non-positive. The reverse is true. All sectional curvatures of $SO(3)$ are non-negative. In fact, the universal cover of $SO(3)$ is $S^3$ and thus what I said is clearly wrong. So can you please give a justification of the existence and smoothness of $A$? Thanks.

Comment: At the very least, the exponential map is a local diffeomorphism near the origin of $T_I(SO(3))$, and thus a lift $A$ is available in a neighborhood of $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ of $0$ in $\mathbf R$. So we have a hanging question: Does there necessarily exist a global lift of $f$, and if not then are there suitable assumptions, like regularity, on $f$ which make a global lift exist?

Comment: In fact a global lift shouldn't always be possible, as is shown by the bump function version of the counterexample given in the post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2313726/can-we-smoothly-choose-a-line-fixed-by-a-smoothly-rotating-rigid-body So the relevant question now is that whether or not a global lift of $f:\R\to SO(3)$ to $T_I(SO(3))$ exist provided we assume that the derivative of $f$ never vanishes.

Comment: @caffeinemachine: Thanks for your comments. There's a lot of math, notation, and terminology in them that I don't know, so I can't completely follow all the ideas you've tossed out. If I'm understanding correctly, then your concern is that although the Euler rotation theorem guarantees the existence of A, it's conceivable that even though $f$ is continuous, it may not be possible to make A a continuous function, even in a neighborhood of $t=0$. Maybe there is a simple way to show this by using the logarithm map: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_group_SO(3)#Logarithm_map [...]

Comment: [...] It looks like $\ln f$ can be expressed in terms of the determinant $D=|f|$, using a function that is continuous for $D\ne0$. The determinant of $f$ is nonzero in some neighborhood of $t=0$, so maybe that patches this hole in my proof?

Comment: My comment starting with "At the very least.." seems to be the same as your last comment. We do not have a problem in a neighborhood of $0$. We can find a smooth map $A:(-\epsilon, \epsilon)\to \text{space of skew-symmetric matrices}$ such that $f(t)=e^{A(t)}$ for all $t\in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, provided $\epsilon$ is small enough. But it is not clear if we can find a continuous map $A$ on all of $\mathbf R$ with the above property.

Comment: @caffeinemachine: I see. So do we agree that it's established that $\omega(t)$ is exists and has the desired properties at a fixed $t$, but are you concerned about the continuity of $\omega$ as a function of $t$? But we know that $\omega$ is continuous in a neighborhood around any $t$, so doesn't that imply that it's continuous everywhere? Or am I still missing your point?

Comment: Consider the exponential map $e:\R\to S^1$, where $S^1$ is the unit circle, and let $f:S^1\to S^1$ be the identity map. In a small enough neighborhood $U_p$ of any point $p$ of $S^1$, one can find continuous map $A:U_p\to \R$ such that $f=e^A$ on $U_p$. But there is no way to find a continuous map $A:S^1\to \R$ such that $f=e^A$ on all of $S^1$. So merely "local existence of lifting" is not sufficient for existence of global lifting. Even so. My head is not completely clear right now. There are two contradictory things which appear to be true to me right now. I'll get some sleep and reply.

Comment: @caffeinemachine: I don't think the example in one dimension is particularly relevant. My proof relies on Euler's rotation theorem, which holds in three dimensions. I'm pretty sure intuitively that my statement about the uniqueness of A is valid, but in any case we don't need global uniqueness, only uniqueness in a neighborhood, in order to get $\omega$ to be unique.